# What is the antonym to ‘minimalist’?

Tags: single-word-requests

There was the following sentence in New York Times (May 26) article titled, “No real hurry to tell the joke -Bob Newhart, Master of the one-sided conversation”

> Bob Newhart has always been a gentle minimalist, which may be why he
>   does not get anywhere near the critical respect of fellow founding
>   fathers of modern stand-up, like Bill Cosby or Lenny Bruce.
>   http://www.nytimes.com/2014/05/27/arts/television/bob-newhart-master-of-the-one-sided-conversation.html?src=dayp

Is there one word antonym to ‘minimalist’? If not, what is the shortest antonym to ‘minimalist’?

Comment: Maximalist is the obvious antonym, but the spell-checker seems to disagree.

Comment: The closest direct antonym I can think of for this usage would be "traditionalist", but that just gets us back to the default case. It sounds like you want a word for someone whose work is more ornate than average. The adjective "rococo" can be idiomatically used to describe that highly-elaborated work, but I don't know of any general term for people who adopt that as a style.

Comment: @Anonym. 'Maximalist' occurred to my mind at first, but I couldn't find it in online dictionaries. I thought I have to look for 'ambitious, avaricious, self-assertive" direction, forgeting about 'xxx-list' variety.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sticking to the context you’ve given, we might say that radically non-minimalist comedians have an **in-your-face** or **over-the-top** style.  This would probably apply to Lenny Bruce, but not to Bill Cosby.  I’m sure there is a more succinct way to express this, however.

A more general antonym is **baroque** (but not for comedians.)

Comment: "Flamboyant" is another.

Answer (score 1):

One antonym of *minimalist* is **[profligate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/profligate).**

As a noun, *profligate* means "a wildly extravagant or self-indulgent person". The word *profligate* is also an adjective (similar to minimalist), meaning "wildly extravagant". An alternate adjective is *prodigal*.

Incidentally, the word *[maximalist](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/maximalist)* is *not* actually an antonym of *minimalist*; on the contrary, it is political jargon meaning "one who advocates immediate and direct action to secure the whole of a program or set of goals".

Comment: Sorry but maximalist is the exact antonym to minimalist. We don't even need to waste time on definitions. Maximalism - as its name suggests - was invented as a response (and in opposition) to Minimalism so is automatically its antonym.

Comment: @TheMathemagician I must respectfully disagree; there are many pseudo-antonyms which appear opposite, but actually are not. For instance, _simulate_ and _dissimulate_, _bar_ and _debar_, and _flammable_ and _inflammable_ are certainly _not_ antonyms, despite their appearance.

Comment: @TheMathemagician Moreover, this source (http://bit.ly/1kFSwNG) provides a detailed etymology of _maximalist_; it is Russian in origin, and had a distinct _political_ meaning.

Comment: "a reaction against minimalism" [Maximalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximalism)

Comment: @TheMathemagician Personally, I find Merriam-Webster more trustworthy than a web encyclopedia that can be edited by anyone. But to each their own...

Comment: Your thought-process appears to be that because a Russian Marxist splinter group called themselves "maximalists" that is now the sole definition of the word in English. Unless Bob Newhart was a secret Marxist-Leninist, sneaking in dialectical materialism into his routines, I think my usage of minimalism/maximalism in the artistic sense is the correct one.

Comment: Maximalist - is having an all-out attitude towards solving problems. May not be the opposite of minimalism, because you could still effect total maximal change using minimal resources.

Comment: I have personally heard “maximalist” used by native speakers in a queer art community. It is slang with a limited group of use but it is used with this intention. Also, “extra.”